# What am I supposed to so with this, nothing I've tried has worked.

Tags: boot, initramfs, busybox

Busybox v1. 22. 1 (Ubuntu 1:1. 22. 0-19ubuntu2) built-in shell (ash) enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

It should be showing you that the file system has uncleaned blocks. The message should be like this:

```
/dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.
/dev/sda1: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
(i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on `/dev/sda1` requires a manual `fsck`

BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in-commands.

(initramfs)_
```

Anyways, you should first determine which partition you need to clean. In the above example, `/dev/sda1` is the partition. According to the example, now you just need to run:

```
fsck /dev/sda1
```

Then press `y` key when asked for confirmation. And after that just press `Enter` when it asks for any more confirmation.
That's all. After it finishes cleaning the partition, type `exit`. And within a few seconds, you will boot up normally.